# How to stop quartz from running in one instance

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have quartz schedulers load balanced across four cluster. Could you please let me know whether we can do some simple operation so it will be block the quartz schedulers from running in one instance.
All my jobs are JDBC store kind of jobs. My requirement is to disabling jobs from kicking off from instance alone from the cluster.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: save a flag somewhere, before job started, it should ask for permission..

Comment: I just want to is this feature available as part of quartz framework.